# What is the correct syntax for a MySQL UPDATE statement to remove non-numeric characters from string

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

Is there a way to remove all non-numeric characters from a nvarchar text string in MySQL?

I kind of got it working with the following select statement but I am having issues on getting the UPDATE statement so I can use the UPDATE on a MySQL trigger everytime something gets inserted or updated. I need to remove the dash "-" and any spaces and only leave all the numeric characters.

Here is a sample of the table structure.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90668/7/0

The field that contain all the dashes and the spaces is 'locationNumber'.

The Select statement that I used for this is the following but no matter how I try to update it I get errors.

select replace(replace(locationnumber, " ", ""),"-","") as locationnumber from test where docid>0;

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: So do you need help with removing non-numeric digits or with a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
update test
    set locationnumber = replace(replace(locationnumber, ' ', ''), '-', '')
```

It does in your SQLFiddle (you have to put it on the "build schema" side).

The syntax in an update/insert trigger would be a bit different.  You would have to do a before insert/update trigger and have logic like:

```
new.locationnumber = replace(replace(old.locationnumber, ' ', ''), '-', '')
```

You would not use an `update` statement at all in a trigger.  You can check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) for more information about trigger syntax.